# IOS how to pass CoreLocation to UiWebView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, geolocation

Question,

Our app uses location services enabled by the CoreLocation Framework. Part of the app has UIWebView that calls data from a site of ours that uses the HTML5 Geolocation function. What ends up happening is that the user views two request location prompts. One for the app and one for the website loaded through the UIWebView.

Is there a way to have the CoreLocation function bypass the UIwebView prompt so the user only has one prompt?

Thanks,
- C

Comment: Has a solution ever been found for this? I'm having the same problem. Request works well in Android but appears twice for iOS